# C++ nested templates: inaccessible static method

Tags: c++, templates

I have a strange (or maybe not) error with the following code:

```
template<typename T>
class Registrer {
public:
    Registrer() {
        Registry::register(T::instance);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class RegisteringClass {
private:
    static const Registrer<T> REGISTRER;
public:
    RegisteringClass () { Q_UNUSED(REGISTRER); /* force static instantiation     */ }
    static const WhatEver *instance() { static T INSTANCE; return &INSTANCE; }
};

template<typename T>
const Registrer<T> RegisteringClass<T>::REGISTRER;

class Something : public WhatEver, RegistringClass<Something> {
}
```

When `instance` method is in the template, I got following error (gcc)

```
error: 'static const WhatEver* RegisteringClass<T>::instance() [with T = Something]' is inaccessible
    static const WhatEver*instance() { static T INSTANCE; return &INSTANCE; }
error: within this context
     Registry::register(T::instance);
In instantiation of 'static const WhatEver* RegisteringClass<T>::instance() [with T = Something]':
```

Whereas when `instance()` is in `Something`, all is fine.

Did I miss some syntax subtlety? Or is this a template limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deriving classes, 'private' is default; 
otherwise you have to use 'public' or 'protected' keyword for EVERY class you derive from:

```
class C : public A, public B 
{
     void f(); 
};
```

Comment: Not when deriving multiple classes. When defining a "class", it always defaults to private, in single and multiple inheritance. When defining a "struct", it always defaults to struct, also in single and multiple inheritance. Also state that the "public/private" keyword affects ONLY to the parent class to which it accompanies, not for all the parent classes, which is the OP actual problem

Comment: OK, I changed my answer for more generality.

Comment: Err… Since there was no mention of visibility in the error message I didn't thought about it…
I've the issue that my subclasses constructors should be private… guess I'll go with friend class